# Android website zooms / scales - iOS fits to screen?

Tags: android, mobile, responsive-design, meta-tags

I'm wondering why, on my **Android** (*HTC Incredible 2*), my website I just published renders zoomed in / scaled initially? While on iPhone / iOS - it renders taking the width and the same as on desktop.

I've built the website on top of the Wordpress Twenty Eleven Theme (*http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/twentyeleven*) - so it has their META still in tact. But I hadn't seen any with an initial scale / zoom in place; I did see a fit width meta. ***EG*** `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

*Is this a preference per my browser within my device that's taking this site this way with the META in place? Is it taking the width per a browser setting, then doing it again view the meta?* ..creating my initial zoom?

**Suggestions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three density categories for Android, by default the target density is set to medium.  The default setting effectively zooms in a page.

To prevent the Android viewport from scaling (zooming in) you can set the viewport density to the device API's.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width" />
```

Targeting device density via CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)" href="hdpi.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.0)" href="mdpi.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 0.75)" href="ldpi.css" />
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#ViewportScale

Above examples were taking from the source link above.